# Convert Time to printable or localtime format

Tags: python

In my python code I get start and end time some thing like:

```
end = int(time.time())
start = end - 1800
```

Now start and end variables holds values like 1460420758 and 1460422558.

I am trying to convert it in a meaningful format like :

```
Mon Apr 11 17:50:25 PDT 2016
```

But am unable to do so, I tried:

```
time.strftime("%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y", time.gmtime(start))
```

Gives me

```
Tue Apr 12 00:25:58 2016
```

But not only the timezone but the H:M:S are wrong

As date returns me the below information:

```
$ date
Mon Apr 11 18:06:27 PDT 2016
```

How to correct it?

Comment: Have you considered pytz for timezone management? http://pytz.sourceforge.net/ It's very difficult to know what's going on based on the code you provided. Not sure if you're changing from time to datetime, etc

Comment: >>> import time
>>> int(time.time())
1460423923
>>> time.gmtime(1460423923)
time.struct_time(tm_year=2016, tm_mon=4, tm_mday=12, tm_hour=1, tm_min=18, tm_sec=43, tm_wday=1, tm_yday=103, tm_isdst=0)
>>> quit()
$ date
Mon Apr 11 18:19:24 PDT 2016

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one involves utilizing datetime to great the format you wish with the strftime module.

What's important is that the time information you get 'MUST' be UTC in order to do this. Otherwise, you're doomed D:

I'm using timedelta to 'add' hours to the time. It will also increments the date, too. I still would recommend using the module I shared above to handle time zones.

```
import time

# import datetime so you could play with time
import datetime

print int(time.time())
date = time.gmtime(1460420758)

# Transform time into datetime
new_date = datetime.datetime(*date[:6])

new_date = new_date + datetime.timedelta(hours=8)

# Utilize datetime's strftime and manipulate it to what you want
print new_date.strftime('%a %b %d %X PDT %Y')
```